# Correct translation of the title from French

Tags: reference-request, calculus-of-variations, translation

It is not a research question. But it is a question to working researchers, who is aware of old and new terminology of calculus of variations. That is why I ask it here.

I want to figure out correct translation of the title of an old article.

The article is about calculus of variations, but unfortunately I am not aware of terminology of the subject.

**The article is**: "Sur les solutions périodiques et les extrémales fermées du calcul des variations. Math. Ann. 110(1935), 63-96."

In particular I can not decide should "extrémales fermées" be translated as "closed extremal" or it should be rather translated as "closed extremum".

Comment: Neither, since it is plural.

Comment: @BenMcKay Ok, Do you know what would be a correct translation of the title?

Comment: How would you distinguish "extrema" from "extremals"? I think they are synonyms, but maybe you have in mind a technical distinction that would be relevant here. For me, I would translate it as "On the periodic solutions and closed extremals of the calculus of variations".

Comment: Definitely extremals ($\ne$ extrema). For me, “On periodic solutions and closed extremals in the calculus of variations”.

Comment: Same as @François Ziegler

Comment: @BenMcKay I think extremals are in the domain of the functional while extrema are in the range. So extremals are the places where extrema are attained.

Comment: From Bliss, "Lectures on the Calculus of Variations", sec. I..7: "An admissible arc defined by functions $y(x), z(x)$ having continuous first and second derivatives, and satisfying the equations (7.1), is called an **extremal**."